# What are the critical points of the function $f(x,y) = (x^2 + y^2) e^{y^2 - x^2}$

Tags: calculus

I'm really having a tough time finding the critical points for this.

For fx=0, I sem to get critical points of x=0, or $x^2 + y^2 = 1$
and for fy=0, I seem to get critical point of y=0 or $x^2 + y^2 = -1$

but I don't know what to do with the second equations of $x^2 + y^2 = 1$ and $x^2 + y^2 = -1$ ...

Comment: Did you not send in this question earlier today? Or a very similar one.

Comment: I did but I still couldn't understand how the results were achieved for: $x^2 + y^2 = 1$ and $x^2 + y^2 = -1$

Answer (score 2):

$$\nabla f(x,y)=\left(2xe^{y^2-x^2}(1-x^2-y^2),2y e^{y^2-x^2}(x^2+y^2+1)\right)$$

since $x^2+y^2\neq -1$ for all $x,y$, the only critical points are given by $(x,y)\in\{(0,0),(1,0),(-1,0)\}$.

Comment: Why not also $(1,0)$ and $(-1,0)$?

Comment: You are right actually, I answered to quickly :-) Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so we have

1. either

   ```
      a) $x=0$
          or
      b) $x^2+y^2 =  1$
   ```
2. either

   ```
      a) $y=0$ 
          or 
      b) $x^2+y^2 = -1$
   ```

First let us decide to write solutions as ordered pairs (x,y) ( to avoid confusion ):

Start assuming 1a true:

```
       Then if 2a) is true we have (0,0)
       Then if 2b) is true we have $y^2 = -1$ and therefore (0,i) or (0,-i)
```

Now   assume 1b true:

```
       Then if 2a) is true x^2 = 1, x = 1 or -1 so (-1,0) or (1,0)
       Then if 2b) is true -1=1 which can never happen
```

All in all we have solutions (0,0),(0,-i),(0,i),(-1,0),(1,0)

Now is a good exercise to plug 'em in check if they work out.

Comment: I might have gotten a sign wrong somewhere, but the important lesson to learn is the systematic approach anyways.